# Sorting for Japanese Language

Tags: sorting, sqlite, icu

I am working on one application which need Sorting in Japanese language.

Sorting of Japanese needs to have Katakana and Kanji converted to Hiragana and then sorted according to the UTF-8 code.

The Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji characters shall be combined together and sorted by the Hiragana equivalent “spelling.” Note: using the Hiragana “alphabet” – a, i, u, e, o, ka, ki, ku, ke, ki, etc.

Can you please tell me how to carry out this task?

Like any logical steps or link etc..

If there is any open source code from where I can get help?